# Spliting variable lenght list in pandas column into columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

In pandas dataframe I have column that looks like this:

```
+----------------------------------------------+
|                carContactTel                 |
+----------------------------------------------+
| []                                           |
| ['tel 432424']                               |
| ['tel 84958358']                             |
| ['tel 5434645', 'tel 534535', 'tel 3242342'] |
+----------------------------------------------+
```

So some list elements are empty.
I'm trying to split this into new columns: `tel1,tel2,tel3,tel4,tel5`.
If list is too short than values in corresponding columns should stay empty.

My last try based on solutions I've found:

```
carContactDF = pd.DataFrame(carContactDF["carContactTel"].to_list(), columns=["carContactTel1", "carContactTel2", "carContactTel3", "carContactTel4", "carContactTel5"])
```

Errors are always about shape of list...tried replacing empty lists wit `'Nan'` but that didn't work too.

Lists are properly generated with another python script so there is no mistake in them...checked.

Error:

> ValueError: 5 columns passed, passed data had 3 columns

Currently 3 items is top but script will run over larger dataset that will have list items with 5 elements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a new dataframe from the `carContactTel` column, then use [`DataFrame.set_axis`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_axis.html) + [`DataFrame.add_prefix`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.add_prefix.html) to conform the columns according to requirements, finally use [`DataFrame.fillna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html) to replace `NaN` values with empty string:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(carContactDF['carContactTel'].tolist())
df1 = (
    df1.set_axis(df1.columns + 1, 1).add_prefix('carContactTel')
    .fillna('').replace('^tel\s*', '', regex=True)
)
```

Result:

```
print(df1)
  carContactTel1 carContactTel2 carContactTel3
0                                             
1         432424                              
2       84958358                              
3        5434645         534535        3242342
```

Comment: `df1 = pd.DataFrame(df['carContactTel'].tolist())`
 gave me    `raise KeyError(key) from err KeyError: 'carContactTel'`

Comment: @Harvey `df` is your `carContactDF` dataframe. Make sure you have replace `df` with `carContactDF`.

Comment: Works! Sorry my mistake. I've concatenated those columns with rest of the dataframe and that's it..thank you!

Comment: @Harvey No problem. Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

Filter rows where the len(carContactTel) < 5 and append na values to those lists. Repeat until done. Then split.

Comment: I don't want to do that. I need elements in all lists regardless of their size to be spit across columns.